# How to get comport data automatically in java using jSerialComm?

Tags: javafx, port

Using this code I am getting the data(data is basically UID of my rfid tag) from comport after clicking on fetch button (represented by doFetch() in code) . When I have to fetch the data of another rfid tag then again I had to press the fetch button. I want it to work in such a way that once I click on the fetch button, it should automatically display the data of rfid tag when it is tapped and then the data of another rfid tag when that is tapped. Means I want to avoid clicking fetch button again and again.
Basically I am reading the UID of rfid tag from comport and then it matches that UID in database and displays the whole data related to that UID in tableView.
I want it to work for just pressing the fetch button once and then I want it to keep on displaying data in tableView on tapping the rfid tags.

Here is my code for controller:

```
public class detectController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TableView<detectBean> tableView;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtSTID;


    ObservableList<detectBean> list;

    public static SerialPort s1;
    static String temp="";
    static String temp1="";

    static void doAlert(String msg)
    {
        Alert alert=new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Alert..");
        alert.setContentText(msg);
        alert.show();
    } 


    ObservableList<detectBean> getRecordsFromTableSome(String sID) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         list=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try {
            pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from stuRegis where studentID=?");
            pst.setString(1, sID);

            ResultSet rs=  pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String studentID1=rs.getString("studentID");
                String studentID = studentID1.substring(1);
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String sroll=rs.getString("sroll");
                String clas=rs.getString("clas");
                String fname=rs.getString("fname");
                String contact=rs.getString("contact");
                String pic = rs.getString("pic");
                FileInputStream photo=new FileInputStream(pic);
                Image image1 = new Image(photo, 100, 100, false, false);
                Date dob=rs.getDate("dob");
                String dobb=dob.toString();
                 Date dos=rs.getDate("dos");
                    String doss=dos.toString();
                detectBean bean=new detectBean(studentID, name, sroll, clas, fname, contact, new ImageView(image1), dobb, doss );
                list.add(bean);
            }

            } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;

  }
    ObservableList<detectBean> getRecordsFromTable() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         list=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try {
              pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from stuRegis");

            ResultSet rs=  pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String studentID1=rs.getString("studentID");
                String studentID = studentID1.substring(1);
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String sroll=rs.getString("sroll");
                String clas=rs.getString("clas");
                String fname=rs.getString("fname");
                String contact=rs.getString("contact");
                String pic = rs.getString("pic");
                FileInputStream photo=new FileInputStream(pic);
                 Date dob=rs.getDate("dob");
                    String dobb=dob.toString();
                 Date dos=rs.getDate("dos");
                    String doss=dos.toString();

                Image image1 = new Image(photo, 100, 100, false, false);
                detectBean bean=new detectBean(studentID,  name, sroll, clas, fname, contact, new ImageView(image1), dobb, doss);
                list.add(bean);
            }

            } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;

    } 

    @FXML
    void doDelete(ActionEvent event) {

        int selectedIndex = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();


        detectBean asm = (detectBean)tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        String selectedItem = asm.getStudentID();


        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {

             try {
                pst = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM stuRegis WHERE studentID = ?");
                pst.setString(1, selectedItem);
                pst.execute();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
             tableView.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);

        } else {
            doAlert("Record deleted successfully");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void doExcel(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            writeExcel();
            doAlert("Exported to excel..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeExcel() throws Exception {
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            FileChooser chooser=new FileChooser();

            chooser.setTitle("Select Path:");

            chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                    new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*")

                );
             File file=chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
            if(!(filePath.endsWith(".csv")||filePath.endsWith(".CSV")))
            {
                doAlert("The File name must have .csv extension");
                return;
            }
             file = new File(filePath);



            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            String text="Student ID, Name, Roll No., Class, Father's Name, Contact No., Date of Birth, Date of Admission\n";
            writer.write(text);
            for (detectBean p : list)
            {
                text =  p.getStudentID()+ "," +p.getName()+ "," + p.getSroll()+ "," + p.getClas()+ "," + p.getFname()+ "," + p.getContact()+"," + p.getDob()+"," + p.getDos()+"\n";
                writer.write(text);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            writer.flush();
             writer.close();
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @FXML
    void doFetch(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        //while(true){
        String a = recall();
        txtSTID.setText(a.substring(1));
        ObservableList<detectBean> list=getRecordsFromTableSome(a);

        //tableView.setItems(list);
        tableView.getItems().addAll(list);
        //}
    }

    @FXML
    void doReset(ActionEvent event) {
        txtSTID.setText("");
        tableView.getItems().clear();
    }

    @FXML
    void doFetchAll(ActionEvent event)throws FileNotFoundException {
        ObservableList<detectBean> list=getRecordsFromTable();
        tableView.setItems(list);
    }

    @FXML
    void doComClose(ActionEvent event) {

        if(s1.closePort()){
            doAlert("Port Closed");
            System.out.println("Port closed successFully");
        }else{
            doAlert("Failed to Close Port");
            System.out.println("Failed to close port");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void doOpenCom(ActionEvent event) {

        port();
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void port() 
    {
        SerialPort[] s=SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for(SerialPort port:s){
            System.out.println(""+port.getSystemPortName());
            s1=SerialPort.getCommPort(port.getSystemPortName());
            if(s1.openPort()){
                doAlert("Port Opened");
                System.out.println("Port opened successFully ");
            }else{
                doAlert("Failed to Open Port");
                System.out.println("Failed to open port");
            }
        }
        s1.setBaudRate(9600);
      s1.n



    }

    public static String recall() throws IOException
    {   
InputStream is=s1.getInputStream();


        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0,x=0;true;i++){
    //for (int i =0;i<11;i++){


        st=st.append((char)is.read());

       temp1=st.toString();

       if(temp1.length()==13)
       { System.out.print(temp1);
         //System.out.print(temp);
         //System.out.print(temp1.length());
           break;
       }
       System.out.print(temp1);


}

//System.out.print(""+(char)is.read());



    temp=temp1.substring(0,11);
    System.out.print(temp.length());
    System.gc();
    return temp;



    }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    PreparedStatement pst;
    Connection con;

    @FXML
    void initialize() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        con=MysqlConnection.doConnect();


        TableColumn<detectBean, String> studentID=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Student ID");//Dikhava Title
        studentID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("studentID"));//bean field name
        studentID.setMinWidth(110);

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> name=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Name");//Dikhava Title
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));//bean field name

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> sroll=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Roll No.");//Dikhava Title
        sroll.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sroll"));//bean field name

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> clas=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Class");//Dikhava Title
        clas.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("clas"));//bean field name

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> fname=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Father's Name");//Dikhava Title
        fname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fname"));//bean field name
        fname.setMinWidth(110);

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> contact=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Contact No.");//Dikhava Title
        contact.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("contact"));//bean field name
        contact.setMinWidth(90);

        TableColumn<detectBean, Image> pic=new TableColumn<detectBean, Image>("Image");//Dikhava Title
        pic.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pic"));//bean field name
        pic.setMinWidth(110);  

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> dob=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Date of Birth");
        dob.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dob"));//field name in bean
        dob.setMinWidth(140); 

        TableColumn<detectBean, String> dos=new TableColumn<detectBean, String>("Date of Admission");
        dos.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dos"));//field name in bean
        dos.setMinWidth(140); 

        tableView.getColumns().clear();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(studentID,name,sroll,clas,fname,contact,pic, dob, dos);








    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: basically you need some kind of signal from the port that there it has new data, then let a background thread wait for that signal and message the fx app with the new data

Comment: Please upload the editted code

Comment: Please tell something !!